# SKLightNode is not zooming with SKCameraNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In Sprite Kit, I'm using an SKCameraNode to zoom in and out of an SKScene. Any SKLightNodes in the scene are not zoomed at all. They are not children of the Camera so should not be invariant. Can't find anything on this - Search "SKLightNode SKCameraNode" on SO yields 0 results.

Using Xcode 8.3.3 and starting from a basic Game/Swift project, I have replaced sceneDidLoad() in GameScene.swift with:

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {

    let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
    cameraNode.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
    self.addChild(cameraNode)
    self.camera = cameraNode

    let bg = SKSpriteNode(color:.red, size:self.size)
    bg.lightingBitMask = 0b0001
    self.addChild(bg)

    let lightNode = SKLightNode()
    lightNode.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
    lightNode.categoryBitMask = 0b0001
    lightNode.lightColor = .white
    lightNode.falloff = 1.0
    self.addChild(lightNode)

    let zoomDuration:TimeInterval = 10.0
    let zoomAction = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.scale(to:0.25, duration:zoomDuration),
        SKAction.scale(to:1.0, duration:zoomDuration)
        ])
    self.camera?.run(zoomAction)

}
```

As you can see, the light stays the same during the zooms.

In an attempt to fix this problem, I've tried the following custom action to modulate the falloff property of the light. It's sort of ok but it's not a faithful zoom.

```
    let lightAction1 = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: zoomDuration) {
        (node, time) -> Void in
        let lightNode = node as! SKLightNode
        let ratio:CGFloat = time / CGFloat(zoomDuration)
        let startFalloff:CGFloat = 1.0
        let endFalloff:CGFloat = 0.25
        let falloff:CGFloat = startFalloff*(1.0-ratio) + endFalloff*ratio
        lightNode.falloff = falloff
    }
    let lightAction2 = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: zoomDuration) {
        (node, time) -> Void in
        let lightNode = node as! SKLightNode
        let ratio:CGFloat = time / CGFloat(zoomDuration)
        let startFalloff:CGFloat = 0.25
        let endFalloff:CGFloat = 1.0
        let falloff:CGFloat = startFalloff*(1.0-ratio) + endFalloff*ratio
        lightNode.falloff = falloff
    }
    let lightSequence = SKAction.sequence([lightAction1, lightAction2])
    lightNode.run(lightSequence)
```

Surely the camera should zoom on the light? Am I missing something?

EDIT: following suggestions below here is some code that scales the SKView:

```
    let originalWidth:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let originalHeight:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

    let lightAction1 = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: zoomDuration) {
        (node, time) -> Void in
        let ratio:CGFloat = time / CGFloat(zoomDuration)
        let startFalloff:CGFloat = 1.0
        let endFalloff:CGFloat = 1.5
        let falloff:CGFloat = startFalloff*(1.0-ratio) + endFalloff*ratio
        self.view?.frame = CGRect(x: (originalWidth-originalWidth*falloff)/2.0, y: (originalHeight-originalHeight*falloff)/2.0, width: originalWidth*falloff, height: originalHeight*falloff)
    }
    let lightAction2 = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: zoomDuration) {
        (node, time) -> Void in
        let ratio:CGFloat = time / CGFloat(zoomDuration)
        let startFalloff:CGFloat = 1.5
        let endFalloff:CGFloat = 1.0
        let falloff:CGFloat = startFalloff*(1.0-ratio) + endFalloff*ratio
        self.view?.frame = CGRect(x: (originalWidth-originalWidth*falloff)/2.0, y: (originalHeight-originalHeight*falloff)/2.0, width: originalWidth*falloff, height: originalHeight*falloff)
    }
    let lightSequence = SKAction.sequence([lightAction1, lightAction2])
    lightNode.run(lightSequence)
```

You will also need to halve the Camera zoom. The only problem with this is that everything is scaled (even nodes added as children to the CameraNode like scores/buttons).

Comment: I don't see anything happening with the view.frame block (third one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to thank you for providing an example we can test.  By playing around with it, I can definitely see the light growing and shrinking but it is not by much, (it is more noticeable if you move the camera off position (0,0)  Perhaps theres a math problem on apples end, or a drawing order priority problem.

I have even attempted to add the SKLightNode to a separate SKNode, and scale the node, but that left the same result.

I also attempted to resize the scene to a larger size, and still the same result.

I then decided to play with the view size,  low and behold I was able to get different results when I adjusted this.  This means that SKLightNode goes off of the SKView size, and not the SKScene size (Really apple?).  Either that or it goes off of the context that the SKView provides.  Either way, looks like you are not zooming with SKLightNode.  (Btw, the shadow still zooms, so perhaps you just need to work in a better lighting affect?)

Comment: Thanks! I don't really want to change the SKView size as this will change sprites and other nodes, won't it? Also not using shadows. SKCamera is good and easy to use for zoom effects but it is annoying that lighting is 'left out'. My workaround is acceptable-ish but still a hack.

Comment: I do not know if changing the view dynamically is even an option,  it would produce some artifacts I will tell you that, but no everything will stay the same size if the view is aspect fill and the scene is aspect fill

Comment: you *can* change the view! Thankfully that frame is editable! `view!.frame.size.height += 2500` totally works @ChristianCerri

Comment: Ok if it works then that is a workaround, but damn is that an ugly work around

Comment: Yes, changing the view.frame works and the light is scaled correctly... BUT you can't use SKCameraNode, which is needed to have invariant nodes. I think varying the falloff, whilst not perfect, is perhaps the best workaround.

Comment: The answer I am really looking for is how to make SKCameraNode and SKLightNode play nice together... Otherwise sounds like a bug report is in order.

Comment: You can use SKCameraNode, you just need to scale both at the same time

Comment: Oh it is def a bug if Fluidity tested the size and it worked.  I would file a report (of course they will just tell you to f off in a polite way)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm you can vary view.frame and use SKCameraNode together. However, any children of the camera (which should stay invariant) are scaled by the view.frame changes.

Comment: I will play with this some more tomorrow,  sounds like the scaling is not doing its job

Comment: @ChristianCerri so I haven't played around with any of this yet, but you could do an old fashioned camera that may work better with your project. Basically you just make a "world" node and move it around. There was a guide on doing that somewhere I can't find it now though. It's a basic 2d camera though from 10-20 years ago.

Comment: @Fluidity, he wants to do scaling though,  I have attempted to try old school camera, did not work. (My first attempt is this method)

Comment: @ChristianCerri, I have been playing around this morning,  I was able to get the view to resize, but the SKScene does not scale with the view, not sure if you or Fluidity were able to get the scene to "resize" with the view. (I put the resize in quotes because I expect the pixel size to be larger, but the point size to stay the same)

Comment: KoD, I meant old school + view frame scaling. Does that not make a difference compared to the CamNode?

Comment: "_I was able to get the view to resize, but the SKScene does not scale with the view_" and can't you just manually scale the scene along with the view?

Comment: The old school method was to just take a node and pan/scale it,  not to use `SKCameraNode`.  You pretty much worked in the opposite direction of the `SKCameraNode`, so for example, if you shift the camera 10 points left, you would have to shift the node 10 points right

Comment: @Fluidity, he wants everything to stay the same size,  this requires we use `aspectFill` methods.  Resizing the scene would make things go smaller, which is more work on the processor to scale it back to size.

Comment: I wonder if recreating the light / camera node after scaling would have any effect?

Comment: @Fluidity, +KoD, thanks for good suggestions. The worldNode idea is good I will try it as I already use it for pausing (don't pause the SKScene!!!). Fundamentally: you have a game with zoomable bits (e.g. sprites) and non-zoomable bits (e.g. scores/buttons). SKCamera handles this well; resizing the view changes the non-zoomable bits as well. Maybe resizing worldNode will work... but then you would need to work around for invariants not added to worldNode. Basically it's getting very complicated and not worth it when modulating .falloff works ok. I just wanted to know if I was missing something

Comment: @ChristianCerri I'm trying to get your code to work but I keep getting a random metal error from the lightnode when it's added. sigh.

Comment: @Fluidity best run on a device, simulator is crap with lights... maybe Xcode 9 will fix this!

Comment: @ChristianCerri haha, I ran it on a mac device :) I always use OSX spritekit builds and runs much faster for my machine at least. Trying it on ios now

Comment: I didnt even think to try it on a real device LOL

Comment: @ChristianCerri I wouldn't bet on it. SK got nothing but ARKit it seems this year.

Comment: @ChristianCerri I just posted this on the SKAlliance slack so maybe you will get some more eyes on this. Could be bounty worhty as well

Comment: definitely not pro, just an avid developer.  Trying to find a way to get this scene to "resize" when the view resizes, otherwise it is going to make some of my iPad development ideas a little disappointing in the future.

Comment: added some view scaling code to the original question - works OK but can't handle invariant nodes (children if SKCamera) like scores

Comment: @ChristianCerri ok your code works fine on iOS. if you are planning to port to macOS then you should know it is crashing :)

Comment: @Fluidity sorry dude MacOS is dead to me, but thanks

Comment: @ChristianCerri @ KoD resetting the lightnode and manually changing its scale as a `.run()` didn't do anything =/

Comment: SKLightNode seems to scale by the SKView size and not by the camera (Really Apple?). The only way to do it seems to be scaling the falloff along with camera zoom. Example: https://dodogames.io/devlog/sklightnode-and-normal-maps/

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that you need to dynamically adjust two parameters as the cameraNode scales: the falloff, and the brightness.

The falloff needs to be multiplied by the square root of the scale.

The brightness needs to be divided by the square root of the scale.

We do this by subclassing SKLightNode, in this example to DXScalableLightNode, and setting up the new class to respond to messages sent when the camera scale changes.

```
class DXScalableLightNode: SKLightNode {
    
    var baseFalloff     : CGFloat
    var baseHue         : CGFloat = 0.0
    var baseSaturation  : CGFloat = 1.0
    var baseBrightness  : CGFloat = 0.0
    var baseAlpha       : CGFloat = 0.0

    init(falloff: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        color.getHue(&baseHue, saturation: &baseSaturation, brightness: &baseBrightness, alpha: &baseAlpha)
        baseFalloff = falloff
        super.init()
        self.lightColor = color
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(scaleDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.cameraScaleDidChange, object: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func scaleDidChange(notification: Notification) {
        guard let scale = notification.userInfo?["scale"] as? CGFloat else {
            fatalError("Notification.cameraScaleDidChange received with no scale")
        }
        falloff     = baseFalloff * sqrt(scale)
        lightColor  = UIColor(hue: baseHue, saturation: baseSaturation, brightness: baseBrightness / sqrt(scale), alpha: baseAlpha)
    }
}
```

Walking through that we first convert the original color to its base HSBA values and store them.

When the scale changes we adjust the falloff and brightness appropriately.

So we our new class and we initialise a light with something like:

```
let myLight = DXScalableLightNode(falloff: 0.75, color: .white)
```

The next step is to make sure your scalable light nodes get informed of scale changes.

In your code, whenever you change the camera scale (say as the result of a pinch gesture), you do this:

```
cameraNode.setScale(newScale)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .cameraScaleDidChange, object: self, userInfo: ["scale": newScale])
```

...which sends a message to every DXScalableLightNode in your scene and adjusts them so that their lighting effect is properly scaled.

Do note that the Apple docs say that SKLightNode.falloff should be in the range 0.0...1.0 and it does appear that using falloffs greater than 1.0 does slightly break things.